# How to wait until environment is non-headless?

Tags: java, linux, headless

I've created a *Java server* that boots up with Ubuntu 12.04 and I've one problem: my code needs a non-headless (or headfull) environment to work, otherwise it throws a HeadlessException:

```
java.awt.AWTException: headless environment
at java.awt.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:91)
at remote_control.RobotThread.run(RobotThread.java:35)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But it seems that my .jar is started **before X server** on startup, so I'm always getting the "HeadlessException". To make my JAR start with my system I have done something like:

```
sudo update-rc.d my_script_to_initiate_my_jar defaults 99 01
```

I haven't found a way to boot the **JAR after X server**, so I think the best way to solve this problem is using busy waiting inside my code. I already checked a lot of questions (at StackOverflow and at Google) and I found some common solutions:

```
// First solution
while (GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Second solution
GraphicsEnvironment ge;
do {
    ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
} while (ge.isHeadless());
```

**Unfortunately these solutions didn't work: isHeadless() always returns true**, so it never exit the loop. And yes, at this time I was already using Unity (the Ubuntu graphical interface), so I already have a "headfull environment". Sorry if I made some mistake, but I'm very newbie with UNIX / Linux.

If you need any further information, please ask me and I will provide it. The solution also must be non-GUI-specific (e.g: only works on GNOME or Unity, must work in all of them).

## Edit

Following you can check my .sh script that is inside `/etc/init.d/` and is responsible to startup the JAR with the system. Contain the script provided by @that-other-guy .

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=labspy_client
PATH_TO_JAR=/var/lib/LabSpy/Student.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/labspy_client_pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
                export DISPLAY=:0
                until xwininfo -root > /dev/null
                do
                    sleep 5
                done
                nohup /opt/java/bin/java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /var/log/labspy_stdout >> /var/log/labspy_stderr &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
                echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
                echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Why not catch the exception and retry after a short delay until your code succeeds ?

Comment: I haven't thought about that O.o I'll try, but I'm still accepting better approaches to solve this problem (instead of busy waiting). Anyway, thank you for the comment!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the environment will never *become* not-headless. Instead, you need to figure out why it wants X and fix that (since it's a server, it shouldn't need it).

Comment: How are you starting your app? It might be possible to make it load after X and other dependencies.

Comment: I've updated the question with my script to initiate the JAR, @SnakeDoc

Comment: did you try adding your app as a startup script in Xsession.d (x server startup) instead of the rc scripts?  (like so https://www.debian-administration.org/article/50/Running_applications_automatically_when_X_starts )

Comment: I didn't know Xsession.d until now, @jtahlborn. But far I see, I must create a file called ".xsession" under my Home directory, right? The problem is that I can't allow users delete this file, cause my JAR is a monitoring software for classrooms and this way students will delete the file. Do you have another suggestion based on Xsession.d? Can I make a script under /etc/xsession/myScript that will initiate when X server starts (or something like that)?

Comment: I know you are on Ubuntu, but does it have something similar to `chkconfig` (from RHEL/CentOS) where you can specify the run-level your script initializes at?  -- Runlevel 5 is what you would be after, since that is when X has started - http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/run-levels-intro.html  - and then you could use a very high `S` number to ensure it starts up last, like `S999yourScript.sh` in the `init.d/rcX.d`

Comment: The equivalent to "chkconfig" in Ubuntu is the "update-rc.d" command. I already have set run levels: 99 to start and 01 to kill. The highest the run level, the later will an application run (and the run levels goes from 0 to 99). This's the recommended for application programs: they will start later [probably after all the dependencies] and will be killed early. I can't start my software later and X server is still starting after that.

Comment: Linux runlevels are 0-6, what you are specifying with 0-99 is startup sequence within that specified runlevel. Runlevel 5 is when X starts and stuff, so you could specify runlevel 5 in your rc.d and starting sequence of 99 to ensure your app is last.

Comment: So try putting/sym-linking your script into `/etc/rc5.d/` and set the starting sequence to 99.

Comment: yes, i was referring to using a global script in /etc/X11/Xsession.d as described in that link i gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display to use for a graphical program is determined using the `DISPLAY` environment variable. This is normally set by and inherited from the X session.

If you think an appropriate display server will be up and running in the near future, you can guess at its display number -- probably `:0` -- and wait for it to respond to things.

I really wouldn't trust Java to re-check whether a display is functional after it first initializes, so here's a shell script loop:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY="/home/youruser/.Xauthority"
until xwininfo -root > /dev/null
do
  sleep 5
done
echo "X server is now running"
```

This is a highly anti-Unix solution caused by your Windows style requirement of assuming that there is exactly one screen and that you need to take control of it.

Well behaving Unix programs would not work against the system like this, and would instead leave it to the user to start the server on the display of their choice.

Comment: I realy liked your solution and I'm trying to implement that, but when I reboot my VM (with the updated JAR [without any busy waiting] and Ubuntu configured to startup the JAR with the system) nothing happens. I'll update my question posting the currently version of my script.

Comment: Please include all four (4) of following: 1. What does `echo $DISPLAY` say when you open an xterm on the display? 2. Which user does your script run as and which user does `echo $USER` say in the xterm? 3. Do your log files get created, indicating that the jar tried to run, and if so, what do they say? 4. What output do you get if you run the script in the xterm?

Comment: (1) `:0.0`   (2) I think should be the `root` user, because it's running on system startup. The requested command returns `batman` [it's my user] (3) No, the files aren't created [and that's why I have said nothing happens]. (4) The same output of the normal terminal (I always run with "sudo"): `Starting labspy_client ...
labspy_client started ...` Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Then can you change `until xwininfo -root > /dev/null` to `until xwininfo -root >> /tmp/xwininfo 2>&1` , reboot, and then `cat /tmp/xwininfo` in the xterm when it comes back up? What does it say?

Comment: Sorry for the delay (that is all the log): https://gist.github.com/paladini/25477f460ad4f4e2600e

Comment: @FernandoPaladini Is the file still being written to as we speak? If not, your system probably kills init scripts that take too long.

Comment: Yes, the file's still being written :O

Comment: Ok, `root` is probably not allowed to run things on your display. Set `XAUTHORITY` to the full path of the X user's `.Xauthority` file. You can run `sudo env -i bash --norc` to get a root shell without the environment set up to more accurately test the script without rebooting.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the .Xauthority file? In what user should I put this file? Also, I shouldn't allow students to change or remove the program from boot (it's a classroom monitoring software), this file inside Home folder will not allow them to do that?

Comment: This file is created by X.org and contains cookies needed to authenticate with the X session. You should use the `.Xauthority` file from the home directory of the user controlling the X session. `batman` in your case.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Just allow me ask some questions before I give you the best answer: Using this file (.Xauthority) at Home folder students will can delete this file and "disable" the startup of my JAR, right? Students can't be allowed to disable this classroom monitoring software. What can be done to solve this problem? Another question: how can I make this script work for any computer? I will install everything remotely, so I'll not know the user name. There's an easy way to do that?

Comment: A robust solution would probably integrate into X and the session rather than being just another client. For your approach, rather than trying to list and patch the various ways a user can prevent your software from interfering with their session, I suggest you just kill their session if you can't access it. As for getting the currently logged in user, I don't have any particularly good suggestions for that.